# Probability of consignment acceptance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

***When a consignment of pens arrives at the retailer's, ten of them are tested. The whole batch is returned to the wholesaler if more than two of those selected are found to be faulty. What is the probability that the consignment will be accepted if 5% of the pens are faulty?***

Our instructor told us this would be solved using the binomial distribution which has a condition that the trials are independent. But if you are testing a batch of pens you would test it without replacement which makes the following trials dependent.

So help me understand why is this solved using the binomial distribution?

Comment: The five$-$percent rule says that if the $\frac{\text{sample size}}{\text{population size}}<0.05$ you can assume we're sampling with replacement. Have you learned about this rule or something similar in your course?

Comment: If only 5% of the pens are defective then the difference between dependent and independent trials is negligible.

Comment: @MatthewH. no, we did not study anything about the five percent rule

Comment: The five percent rule is why you can assume sampled items are approximately independent. It's safe to assume the wholesaler's supply of pens (i.e. the population size) is significantly larger than the sample size of $10$.

Comment: @MatthewH. ah ok thanks for the answer

Comment: @MatthewH. i could not find any source for this rule

Comment: https://stats.libretexts.org/Courses/Diablo_Valley_College/Math_142%3A_Elementary_Statistics/Math_142%3A_Course_Material/05%3A_Chapter_5/Ch_3.4_Sampling_with_without_replacement#:~:text=When%20sampling%20without%20replacement%20and,though%20they%20are%20actually%20dependent.)

Comment: Personally, I initially questioned whether one might assume that the defect of one pen in a batch and defect of another pen in a batch are independent events.  Unfortunately, in my opinion, that idea doesn't seem to hold water, for two reasons: [1] If they are independent events, there is no reason to reject a batch, simply because $3$ or more pens among the $(10)$ tested are found to be defective. [2] In a real world context, it makes sense that a temporary manufacturing malfunction would affect a disproportionately hign percentage of the pens in a group.